# Completely disable NetworkManager from using DHCP client?

Tags: rhel, ip, networkmanager, dhcp, assignment

I am using RHEL 7.9.
This version of RHEL I use `nmcli` and `nmtui` to configure network connections.

Problem:

NetworkManager service appears to be filling up journalctl logs with the following output

```
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7165] device (p2p3_2): Activation: starting connection 'p2p3_2' (49fb6e36-468f-4a5b-8015-4d6e7728f82c)
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7167] device (p2p3_4): Activation: starting connection 'p2p3_4' (673b8472-90f0-4e7d-ace2-91f912c94b1d)
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7168] device (p2p3_2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7172] device (p2p3_4): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7176] device (p2p3_2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7194] device (p2p3_4): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7212] device (p2p3_2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:03 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780963.7221] device (p2p3_4): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1650780966.7132] dhcp4 (p2p3): request timed out
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7132] dhcp4 (p2p3): state changed unknown -> timeout
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7214] dhcp4 (p2p3): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 78427
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7214] dhcp4 (p2p3): state changed timeout -> done
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7217] device (p2p3): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1650780966.7222] device (p2p3): Activation: failed for connection 'p2p3'
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7224] device (p2p3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7329] policy: auto-activating connection 'p2p3' (0af065ee-a8a0-997a-c03a-b737387d1a9f)
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7333] device (p2p3): Activation: starting connection 'p2p3' (0af065ee-a8a0-997a-c03a-b737387d1a9f)
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7333] device (p2p3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7337] device (p2p3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7434] device (p2p3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7437] dhcp4 (p2p3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 24 02:16:06 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780966.7448] dhcp4 (p2p3): dhclient started with pid 78439
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1650780967.7124] dhcp4 (p2p4): request timed out
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7124] dhcp4 (p2p4): state changed unknown -> timeout
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7206] dhcp4 (p2p4): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 78433
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7206] dhcp4 (p2p4): state changed timeout -> done
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7207] device (p2p4): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1650780967.7211] device (p2p4): Activation: failed for connection 'p2p4'
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7213] device (p2p4): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7319] policy: auto-activating connection 'p2p4' (8cd96d38-f953-c130-f247-05b56972a953)
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7321] device (p2p4): Activation: starting connection 'p2p4' (8cd96d38-f953-c130-f247-05b56972a953)
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7322] device (p2p4): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7325] device (p2p4): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7422] device (p2p4): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7424] dhcp4 (p2p4): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 24 02:16:07 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780967.7435] dhcp4 (p2p4): dhclient started with pid 78445
Apr 24 02:16:08 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780968.7125] policy: auto-activating connection 'p2p4_1' (ff70a4ab-0b4b-4558-bf07-e24aa8319e72)
Apr 24 02:16:08 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780968.7129] device (p2p4_1): Activation: starting connection 'p2p4_1' (ff70a4ab-0b4b-4558-bf07-e24aa8319e72)
Apr 24 02:16:08 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780968.7130] device (p2p4_1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:08 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780968.7134] device (p2p4_1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:08 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780968.7154] device (p2p4_1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:13 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780973.7115] device (p2p3_5): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:13 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1650780973.7119] device (p2p3_5): Activation: failed for connection 'p2p3_5'
Apr 24 02:16:13 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780973.7122] device (p2p3_5): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 24 02:16:13 taxmd-trex-02 NetworkManager[1431]: <info>  [1650780973.7150] policy: auto-activating connection 'p2p3_5' (a70daadb-15be-4233-807e-3a09e94fdd3e)
```

This repeats for all interfaces without an ip address assigned.

I think this is dhcp related. I do not want any dhcp client to be running on any interface. Some of these interfaces will have static addresses, others will not. It seems the interfaces that do not have an IP address, NetworkManager by default uses auto configuration and tries to get DHCP. I can assign link-local, and it will grab an APIPA address, I dont want that either.

Is it possible to just have an enabled interface with NO ip address. And make NetworkManager stop trying to get an IP?